# How to read from Process inputStream not immediately available

Tags: java, fork, inputstream

In Java reading from inputStream of Process works has expected if data is immediately available. 
But when process will not produce data immediately, it seems to be impossible to retrieve data?!

Unit test :

```
@Test
public void testForkingProcess() throws Exception {
            String [] cmds = new String[]{"echo this is a test", "sleep 2 ; echo this is a test"};
    for(String cmd: cmds) {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        byte[] buf = new byte[100];
        int len = 0;
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(len < 15 && (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) < 5000) {
            int newLen = p.getInputStream().read(buf, len, buf.length - len);
            if(newLen != -1) {
                len += newLen;
            }
        }
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("elapse time : " + (t1 - t0) +" ms");
        System.out.println("read len : " + len);            
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

Console output :

```
    elapse time : 1 ms
    read len : 15
    elapse time : 5000 ms
    read len : 0
```

Is someone has a clue about this behavior and how to process the stream to retrieve data.

An other simple example :

```
@Test
public void testMoreSimpleForkingProcess() throws Exception {
    String [] cmds = new String[]{"echo this is a test", "sleep 2 ; echo this is a test"};
    for(String cmd: cmds) {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        byte[] buf = new byte[100];
        int len = 0;
        int newLen = 0;
        while(newLen >= 0) {
            newLen = p.getInputStream().read(buf, len, buf.length - len);
            if(newLen != -1) {
                len += newLen;
            }
        }
        p.getInputStream().close();
        System.out.println("read len : " + len);            
        p.destroy();
    }

}
```

Console Output :

```
    read len : 15
    read len : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to read from Process inputStream not immediately available?

Block. You don't need the timing stuff. You don't know how fast the process is going to produce output. Just block in read, and repeat until end of stream.

You also need to consume the error stream, and you also need to close the process's input stream. You're also sleeping while end of stream has already been received. Pointless.

Comment: ok but how to block ? First call to read directly return end of stream (-1)

Comment: Block for what? You've reached end of stream: so, stop reading, close the stream, you're done.

Comment: ok thank's for reply in fact I am not expecting error in exec and I think that even if stream return -1 it could return data later.
I will never forget to read error stream now !!

Comment: No. If the read returns -1 it can never 'return data later'. There is no more data. The peer has closed his end of the pipe. And you must always expect an error in `exec()`, and in anything else too.

Answer (score -1):

Ok in fact issue is in cmd pass to exec Java not process command like shell. 
need to used ProcessBuilder and bash -i -c